# Instagram API Python: pagination for api.tag_recent_media

Tags: python, instagram-api

I this script in Python to search photos through keywords, here you have the code:

```
       api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
       tag_name = raw_input("Inserisci la parola chiave da cercare")
       filtered_media = api.tag_recent_media(count=40, max_id=1, tag_name=tag_name)
```

but my problem is that even though I write `count=40` I can only download 33 images.
How can I solve it?

EDIT: reading trough the site I saw that pagination is needed, but i'm still confused: should I change `max_id` and `min_id` parameter or work with `next_url` parameter?

anyone can please provide some examples/tutorial/explanations somewhere in the web? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked the instagram api limits? https://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: reading some similar posts I saw that maybe it's a problem of pagination rather than limit..

Comment: Did you ever figure out whether to use the max_id or the pagination url that comes back? It seems weird to start using an http variable when the first request was made using the python library.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next page as follows:

```
tag_recent_media, next_ = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name="whatever_tag")
tag_recent_media, next_ = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name="whatever_tag", with_next_url=next_)
```